# How to write and save a file multiple times with StreamWriter in C#?

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I'm trying to open a file, rewrite it, save it and close it for multiple times in my app, and I observed a strange behavior

I open the file with:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
```

Write it with this:

```
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)) {
            file.WriteLine(myString);
            file.Close();
        }
```

But the file does not change until I close the app, why is this happening ?

I checked the file myself and it content doesn't change just after the app is closed

Comment: Have you considered using [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I already done that, I read the file, delete it, and use File.AppendAllText, I'm just curios about this behavior and why it occurs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not flushing the changes to disk. This is probably due to the open `StreamReader` handle. Close the reader after each write and re-open it. Or better close the reader before you write and re-open it afterwards.